# Big-O complexity of a recurrence function $8 \cdot T(\frac{n}{4})+O(n\cdot\sqrt{n})$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

An algorithm solves a problem of size $n$ by recursively calling

**8 subproblems, with each subproblem of 1/4 the size of the original input**.

It then combines their solutions to form the solution of the original problem in $\mathbf{O(n\cdot sqrt(n))}$ time.

I already have the recurrence equation of $8 \cdot T(\frac{n}{4})+O(n\cdot\sqrt{n})$ figured out but I have no idea how to calculate the Big-O portion. I know it has something to do with the master theorem/iteration method, but how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated we can solve the recurrence using the iteration method. Given the recurrence:

$$ T(n) = 8 T \left( \frac{n}{4} \right) + n^{\frac{3}{2}} $$

We expand the first few terms getting:

$$ T(n) = n^{\frac{3}{2}} + 8 \left( \frac{n}{4} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} + 8^2 \left( \frac{n}{4^2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} + 8^3 \left( \frac{n}{4^3} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} + ... + 8^{\log_4 n} T(1) $$

Rewriting we get:

$$ T(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_4 n} \left( \frac{8}{4^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)^k n^{\frac{3}{2}} = n^{\frac{3}{2}} \sum_{k = 0}^{\log_4 n} 1 = n^{\frac{3}{2}} \log_4 n $$

And so we conclude:

$$ T(n) = O\left(n \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_4 n\right) $$

We could have also used the master theorem to deduce the solution. The master theorem applies to recurrences of the form:

$$ T(n) = a T \left( \frac{n}{b} \right) + f(n) $$

In our problem $a = 8$, $b = 4$ and $f(n) = n \sqrt{n}$. This means $\log_b a = \log_4 8 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $f(n) = n^{\log_b a}$ and so the second case of the master theorem applies. Then, the master theorem states the solution to the recurrence to be:

$$ T(n) = O\left( n \sqrt{n} \cdot \log_2 n \right) $$